# load list into separate variables with varying names

Tags: bash, variables, dynamic

Debian testing, bash...

I'm trying to load variables from existing programs.

**Set Programs Variable**

```
xPROGS="$(echo -e "exiftool\nrsync\nxsel")"
```

**Attempt to create variables with x(program name)**

```
echo "$xPROGS" | while read z; do x$z="$(whereis -b "$z" | awk '{print $2}')" ; done
```

**Errors;**

```
bash: xexiftool=/usr/bin/rsync: No such file or directory
bash: xrsync=/usr/bin/rsync: No such file or directory
bash: xxsel=/usr/bin/rsync: No such file or directory
```

This works;

```
$ whereis -b rsync | awk '{print $2}'
```

I can't achieve varying the variable name successfully.

Could someone please help.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables

Comment: The errors messages are reported because bash does not understand the  command (x$Z=...) as a variable assignment. Therefore it is understood as a external command named "xexiftool=/usr/bin/rsync" to load and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

progs=(exiftool rsync xsel)

for prog in "${progs[@]}"; do
        read -r _ "x${prog}" _ <<< "$(whereis -b "${prog}")"
done

echo "exiftool: [${xexiftool}]"
echo "rsync:    [${xrsync}]"
echo "xsel:     [${xxsel}]"
```

```
$ ./t.sh
exiftool: []
rsync:    [/usr/bin/rsync]
xsel:     []
```

Comment: Sorry, the code should have been... $ echo "$xPROGS" | while read z; do x$z="$(whereis -b "$z" | awk '{print $2}')" ; done . Does that change your recommendation ? Thanks.

Comment: @voiczed No, this achieves what you are after in an idiomatic way and without forking unnecessarily.

Comment: Works! Thank you. Is it possible to make 1 line ? This didn't work: $ for prog in "${progs[@]}"; do read -r _ "x${prog}" _ <<< "$(whereis -b "${prog}")" ; done

Comment: @voiczed Did you set `progs=(exiftool rsync xsel)` first? Alternatively, you can do `for prog in exiftool rsync xsel; do read -r _ "x${prog}" _ <<< "$(whereis -b "${prog}")" ; done`.

Comment: Yes, don't you mean: progs="exiftool rsync xsel" ? Thank you for the one liner and the help. Cheers. [SOLVED]

Comment: @voiczed No, `foo=(bar quux)` is an array. You can certainly do `progs="exiftool rsync xsel` and loop over it using word splitting `for prog in ${progs}; do`, but using an array is more elegant and allows for filenames with whitespace. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

@Etan Reisner provided the link from where the following codes are based:

```
echo "$xPROGS" | while read z; do IFS= read -r "x$z" <<<$(whereis -b rsync | awk '{print $2}') ; done
```

But I feel that the rsync command will not change its location in the file system tree

```
RSYNC=$(whereis -b rsync); RSYNC="${RSYNC#* }"; echo "$xPROGS" | while read z; do IFS= read -r "x$z" <<<"$RSYNC" ; done
```

Comment: with bash, `declare "x$z=$RSYNC"` also works. You should avoid ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES when possible (don't accidentally use `PATH=foo`)

Comment: So sorry. originally 'rsync' should have been "$z". I tried to substitude with your recommendation, but echo $xrsync was blank.